# How to get word by word from a string using shell

Tags: shell, unix

I know that the following command counts the number of specific characters in a string variable.

> x="This is a test"
>
> grep -o "s" <<<"$x" | wc -l

What I need is a command that counts the number of words in a string variable and gets all the words one by one, in a loop.

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use bash arrays:

```
x="This is a test"
arr=($x)

echo "No of words:" "${#arr[@]}"
No of words: 4

# to print all array elements
printf "%s\n" "${arr[@]}"
This
is
a
test

# to iterate the string word by word
for w in "${arr[@]}"; do
    echo "$w"
done
```